# WIFI data transfer stops when traffic increases over an old and 25 meter long RJ45 cable

Tags: wireless-networking, router, ethernet, rj-45

In my home I'm using a 25 meter RJ45 cable to feed a remote part of the house with Internet. I installed a D-Link router (now that I'm at work I don't have the model specs, but it costed 130 € and is probably 4 years old) that has a 4 port RJ45 Hub and an antenna for WIFI.

While the transfer rate over cable does not give any problems, it seems that the WIFI signal is dependent on the load that is produced over Ethernet. If the load is high, then the devices that are connected through WIFI suffer timeouts, losses and total freezings that are only solved with a reset of the router. I had switched the frequencies of the WIFI Signal from auto to all specific frequencies in the past and the guys I'm living with suggest me to buy a new router, but to me it looks more like a cable issue.

The cable was already there when I moved in that flat about 17 years ago. I have a fiber Internet connection and none of these issues show up on the other router. Can these issues be related to the cable? Do I have to buy a new cable or a new Router? Any comment is appreaciated. Martin

Comment: How many devices are connected to the Wifi router? Could it be one of those is causing problems?

Comment: Cables ***can*** emit electromagnetic interference (EMI) but ethernet should not be at any frequency that would interfere with WiFi. It is possible that the router internal bandwidth is not high enough to support both WiFi and ethernet at the same time and Ethernet, being lower latency, essentially steals all the available bandwidth but I'd be surprised if that were the case. Or it could be poor shielding or power supplies inside the router causing interference. USB3 devices connected to your computer with poorly shielded cables can definitely cause interference.

Comment: Why do you assume it's a problem with the Wi-Fi signal by itself? All data transferred by your Wi-Fi devices _also_ goes through the same old Ethernet cable as well – so it's not any kind of weird interference, it's literally that the cable is carrying data unreliably.

Comment: @Berend: Usually there are up to 3 devices connected. Two smartphones and a notebook. I was only told today that performance drops significantly if I am around (1 Iphone/PC with Ethernet and constant Virtual-Desktop_connection once I am at home)

Comment: @user1686: that is what I am trying to find out here. I also think that it's not the signal but the data transferred by WIFI to the router. If Ethernet has lower latency and therefore is processed priorly to WIFI Data as Mokubai says, then in case of a bottleneck it is the one that would suffer losses. I will first try to buy a new cable

Comment: So it could be caused by the virtual desktop software you're using? Just trying to pinpoint the exact bottleneck here.

Comment: @Berend: theoretically possible but I don't know how likely this is. I'm running CITRIX Workspace

Comment: Well, it's just guess. In the end we need to rule out as many factors as possible, and checking to see if it works w/o Citrix is easy to do. If that doesn't fix it, try turning off each device separately, and see if that makes a difference. On the mobiles, you can also check if there's an app that uses excessive data. Another thing you could do is to run speedtest.net on different locations: Close to where internet enters your house, on your laptop connected to the Wifi router (both cabled and wireless), and on the smartphones. This will give us some idea about the speeds we're talking about.

Comment: @Berend: Thanks for these suggestions. Until now these were just sensations and hardly measurable as these losses in performance sneak in slowly until nothing is working anymore, which makes it difficult to relate them to a specific event. And then they do not affect myself but my flatmate, with a less-scientific approach to trouble shooting.